# How to save foreign key referenced model instance when parent model instance is created in Django

Tags: django, django-models

I have Two model Packet and Transaction. And Transaction has many-to-one relationship with Packet. I want to create first Transaction when the Packet is created.

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    """
    :param args:
    :param kwargs:
    :return:
    """

    self.created_on = datetime.datetime.combine(self.created_on.date(),
                                                datetime.datetime.now().time()).replace(tzinfo=utc)
    self.updated_on = datetime.datetime.now().replace(tzinfo=utc)
    if self.pk is None:
        from girvi.models import Transaction
        t = Transaction(type='0', description='0',
                        amount=self.total_worth, packet=self.id,
                        created_on=self.created_on, updated_on=self.updated_on,
                        remark='First amount', roi_charged=self.roi_charged,
                        min_int_period=self.min_int_period)
        t.save()
    return super(Packet, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

How do i create Transaction instance when Packet instance is created so that First Transaction is automatically added when new Packet is created.

Comment: Well, you seem to be doing that already. What's not working?

Comment: Maybe what you want to do is call `super(Packet..` before creating the transaction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create the Packet object (ie. calling the `super()` method) before creating the transaction. This way you can provide the right Packet object to the transaction you creates.

```
    if self.pk is None:
        from girvi.models import Transaction
        new_packet = super(Packet, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
        t = Transaction(type='0', description='0',
                        amount=self.total_worth, packet=new_packet,
                        created_on=self.created_on, updated_on=self.updated_on,
                        remark='First amount', roi_charged=self.roi_charged,
                        min_int_period=self.min_int_period)
        t.save()
    return
```